# How to do a jQuery version of an a-name link?

Tags: jquery

I would like to have a name link type effect where instead of it working like the regular html version:

```
<a href="#take-me-down">Take me down the page</a>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<a name="take-me-down">Hi there</a>
```

it will instead have a nice "slide down the page to that portion" effect. Kind of like those "back to top" links some sites have in their footers which when clicked takes the user to the top of the page by smoothly sliding them up.

How can this be done using jQuery?

Comment: Have you searched with your favorite search engine already? I found this: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=jquery+smoth+scroll

Comment: +1 for an awesome link ;) Just use the code from the first Google result, as it works for an arbitrary number of anchors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At Stack Overflow, we use the [jQuery ScrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo). (It's included at the top of our [user-page.js](http://sstatic.net/js/user-page.js)).

In your example, you could do

```
$('#take-me-down').click(function() {
    $.scrollTo($('a[name="take-me-down"]'), 400);
    return false;
});
```